# how to get data in promise { } object

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing, promise

I use node.js.

I use parallel method in async module to control asynchronous.

In each task function, run python code and get result.

But that result wrapped up in the Promise object.

**code**

```
const tasks = [
    function(callback) {
        pythonShell.run(options, (err, jsonArray)=> {
            callback(null, jsonArray)
        }
    },
    function(callback) {
        pythonShell.run(options, (err, jsonArray)=> {
            console.log(jsonArray) //1
            callback(null, jsonArray)
        }
    }
]

async.parallel(tasks, (err, results) => {
    if (err) return err.message
    console.log(results)//2
});
```

**first console.log**

```
Promise {
    [{...}, {...}]
}
```

**second console.log**

```
[
    Promise {
        [{...}, {...}]
    },
    Promise {
        [{...}, {...}]
    }
]
```

I only want json array in Promise { ... }

How can I get it?

Comment: Try replacing `console.log(results)` with `Promise.all(results).then(console.log)`?

Comment: Simply use `.then(array => { /* Do something with the array of results */ })`

Answer (score 0):

use .then((array_of_data_variable) =>  {

your desired action over here(display to user, save to json etc)

}

this is using the ES6 syntax style.